# I'm trying to save an Image that I rendered and can see in the UV/Image Editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, node-editor, compositing-nodes

As the title states, I am trying to save an image that I can see normally in the UV/Image Editor. I have done some compositing to it, and everything works inside Blender, but when I press F3 and save it to my desktop, the file that shows up there is blank, transparent. I have 3 render layers, all being affected by my composite nodes. In the layers tab at the bottom of the UV/Image Editor screen, I have Composite selected. It looks great inside of Blender, and I don't see why this isn't working.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!
If any extra info or screens are needed to try to help me solve the problem, please request!

Comment: Can we see the node setup (compositing) please?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4JnZbrt.jpg

Comment: Anything useful come up yet?

Comment: It's hard to tell, because the image resolution is not enough in this case. Is that Render Layers node in the bottom right, just above the nearest spaceship wing? It's showing there's no infromation.

Comment: It actually does have a render, but is a really light slipstream type effect, and if I zoom in enough, you can see it slightly http://i.imgur.com/0lUG2L4.png

Comment: Please upload and image that shows the node setup in a readable manner? I can't even find the composite or the viewer nodes...

Comment: How about uploading the Blend? As far a I can see, nothing is wrong with the nodes in the image. As you can see the backdrop is rendering properly.

Comment: Here's the blend itself, sorry for it being so cluttered. https://www.mediafire.com/?bh9o9p120pw5b4m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the image you are saving is entirely transparent except for the lights on the wings. You can't see this in blender because you have selected the *RGB* display mode, which disables the effect of the alpha channel. If you select the *RGBA* display mode in the header of the image editor, then the problem becomes clear:

[image]

As a quick fix, you could disable *Use Alpha* on the composite node and then save the image as RGB instead of RGBA.

However, in case you want an alpha channel, then the cause of this lies in your compositing setup (Be sure to select *RGBA* in the header here too, so you can see what's going on).

Mix/Add nodes don't handle alpha very smartly on their own, so you'll have to handle alpha for them, or use some *alpha over* nodes.

Also note that add nodes literally just add the values of all the pixels together. As a result your spaceships are coming out a few times brighter than they would be.

Here I've remade your compositing setup, working from the bottom (here the bottom is the background, which goes under all other elements) to the top (lens flairs/bloom effects generally go above all other elements):

[image]

Compositing things in this order makes a lot of this alpha handling unnecessary, and generally avoids extra headaches.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I am gonna try doing this now and I'll tell you the results I get.

Comment: I tried it out, and when I went to save it as a RGB it gave me the same black background with white light spots where the headlamps should be, could you send me that blend you fixed up please? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Cold999 I forgot to mention that you'll still need to disable *Use Alpha*. Otherwise the alpha channel will still affect the output, but will appear as black instead of transparent. I've uploaded the .blend with the reworked composite nodes

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Really helped me out and it works like a charm!